# I get build failed if i try to migrate using the package management console

Tags: c#

if I try to migrate my model class to database in vs using the package management console i gets build failed without any explanations.
I want to get that problem fixed. i will be happy if I am referred to a legit video to help me fixed my problem. Or better still if I get a link to any documentation on that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add details about your problem, error codes, VS version, steps you take, etc.